# Possible memory leak on Visual Studio 2013 Update 5?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Visual studio 2013 is randomly crashing after I updated it to 5 RTM.

I found that crashing doesn't happen in safemode. And I found abnormal memory behavior of Visual Studio 2013, and it seem it is related to crashing.

I checked the memory usage of the Visual Studio with VMMAP program, and it showed the memory usage is abnormally increasing. This image was captured during I just loaded a c# wpf application and leave it (I didn't do anything with the Visual Studio). Also CodeLens was turned off.

It just increased and crashed just after the memory usage met about 3.5 GB (it seems like the maximum memory size 32bit application can use). The graph shows the heap usage is the most contribution to the total memory usage increasing (this is why I say possible 'memory leak').

[VMMAP Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsIPQ.png)

These are the plugins installed on Visual Studio (most of them came with the initial Visual Studio installation).

[Plugins List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS3Px.png)

Anybody have any ideas to tackle this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Unless things have changed lately, 32 bit app should choke at 2 GB. 3 GB for a service.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

I think I just have found a solution.

Source Control is the problem.

I just set 
Options -> Source Control -> Current source control plug-in -> None
(It was Microsoft Git Provider.)

The memory usage dropped down drastically.

It seems like that Microsoft Git Provider has some issues.